# Circular outline for radio input

Tags: html, css, focus, border-radius

I am using a HTML radio input rather than building my own. Normally I would use box-shadow for setting a focus style so that it matches the border-radius. When I try the box-shadow approach and set the border-radius to 100%, it doesn't work - it's a rectangle.

For that reason I am using outline:

```
input[type=radio]:focus-visible {
  outline: auto 2px #1DA2BD;
}
```

https://codepen.io/cssgrid/pen/jOYmxyQ

The outline is a slightly weird-looking rounded square rather than a circle.

[image]

Is there any way to make it a circle?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D That is not correct. `box-shadow` will match the border-radius of most HTML elements

Answer (score 0):

No; outlines cannot be made into a circle.

To solve your problem in a cross-browser way, you would have to do quite a few things:

- find a way to get a radio button to appear in a consistent way - this normally involves hiding the original one with `clip()` and styling a label attached to it
- perhaps creating an extra div to provide the border / border-radius to "outline" it

As you might guess, this is quite an involved process.

Instead, you might prefer to use a library for the radio buttons instead, like https://baseweb.design/components/radio/

Comment: "No; outlines cannot be made into a circle" 
It depends on the browser. I think it is only Safari where you can't have a circular outline.
https://codepen.io/cssgrid/pen/popwrRx

Answer (score 0):

Use The **::before** and **::after** selector approach to make perfact circle

Attache snippet will help you

```css
.dinput-radio--input {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
}

.dinput-radio--control {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 6px solid #cccccc;
    transition-property: border-color;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.dinput-radio--control::after {
    content: '';
    top: 14px;
    right: 14px;
    bottom: 14px;
    left: 14px;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1ba1bc;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.dinput-radio--control::before {
    content: '';
    top: 4px;
    right: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;border: 4px solid #1ba1bc;
}


.dinput-radio--input:checked ~ .dinput-radio--control {
    border-color: #1ba1bc;
}

.dinput-radio--input:checked ~ .dinput-radio--control::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.dinput-radio--input:checked ~ .dinput-radio--control::before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <label>
      <input class="dinput-radio--input" required="" name="gender" type="radio" value="male" aria-required="true">     
      <span class="dinput-radio--control"></span>
      Yes 
  </label>
<br>
  <label>
    <input class="dinput-radio--input" required="" name="gender" type="radio" value="male" aria-required="true">     
    <span class="dinput-radio--control"></span>
    No 
</label>
```